# Deserialize JSON in Dictionary in Web Api: always empty string

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc, json, asp.net-web-api

I have such JSON string:  `{"1":[1,3,5],"2":[2,5,6],"3":[5,6,8]}`

I want to send it to the Web Api Controller without changing using ajax request:

`$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "Api/Serialize/Dict",
        data: JSON.stringify(sendedData),
        dataType: "json"
    });`

In Web Api I have such method:

```cs
[HttpPost]
public object Dict(Dictionary<int, List<int>> sendedData)
{
    var d1 = Request.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync().Result;
    var rawJson = new StreamReader(d1).ReadToEnd();
    sendedData=Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<int, List<string>>>(rawJson);
    return null;
}
```

But `rawJson` always is empty string. I don't understand why? 
But `d1.Length` is the same as in JSON string. I don't know how to get JSON string from `d1`...

Thank you!

Comment: try using [FromBody] attribute `public object Dict([FromBody] Dictionary<int, List<int>> sendedData)`

Comment: I tried - the same situation...

Comment: replace type of sendedData with object and see what you indeed get there

Comment: use content type parameter instead of `dataType` when performing ajax call: `contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8"`

Comment: Thank You! I even don't know, how I missed it! It works!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use content type parameter instead of dataType when performing ajax call:

```
$.ajax({ 
       type: "POST",
       url: "Api/Serialize/Dict", 
       contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8", //!
       data: JSON.stringify(sendedData) 
});
```